# File created date is not shown in lwc

Tags: contentversion

I can only find the created date value in the content version object,when I query this field -createddate ,I get only the created date of the record not the original date when the file was created.

Is there a way to get the original date of the file created

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A file's local creation date timestamp that you would see in a directory listing or properties dialog is metadata that is stored outside of the file's main content. Aside from the file's name and [MIME content type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-8.3.1), none of that metadata is typically uploaded to Salesforce, so it can't be recovered from the `ContentVersion` data.

If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) for inserting or updating binary data, you'll see that a typical upload looks like this:

```
--boundary_string
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_document";
Content-Type: application/json

{  
    "Description" : "Marketing brochure for Q1 2011",
    "Keywords" : "marketing,sales,update",
    "FolderId" : "005D0000001GiU7",
    "Name" : "Marketing Brochure Q1",
    "Type" : "pdf"
}

--boundary_string
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Body"; filename="2011Q1MktgBrochure.pdf"

Binary data goes here.

--boundary_string--
```

As you can see, the `entity_document` contains the non-file data, like the `Keywords` field, while the file data `Body` includes just the content type and file name. There's no mention of additional file metadata, because none is uploaded. This is really a limitation of the HTTP standards; any site not using a custom client would have the same limitations.

However, with the [Create Audit Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386699&type=1) permission enabled, it would be possible to send the `CreatedDate` field, as mentioned in [Considerations and activation of 'Create Audit Fields'](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386065&type=1). However, this would require additional specific preparation of the `ContentVersion` data that you want to upload, and requires the "Modify All Data" permission to write to these fields. In other words, it's not practical for most use cases.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox

Comment: since I am writing a custom lwc component to get file upload and display and we cant use the modify all data permission